# How do i create a full screen background for my website?

Tags: html

I have this following code

```
<img  src='https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/fresh_snow.png ' style='position:center; top,left:0px; width,max-height:100%; border:0;' />
```

But i would like to make it full screen with the text showing and have no idea what to do. I have looked at other posts here but it hasn't helped me i'm afraid.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: "I have looked at other posts here" -- Looking won't fix your issue. What have you *tried*?

Comment: Ive only tried the code i added so far that all @Wes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading up on CSS to get an understanding of it rather than trying to find an answer here. Assuming you want the image to be the background of the entire page:

```
body {
  background: url(https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/fresh_snow.png) top left;
}
```

[Treehouse is a good place to start.](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/topic:css)

Comment: Sure im a total beginner at CSS @Phix so yes i will.  Thanks  I would like that imkage to be the background of the entire page but it overlaps my text when i tried

Comment: @RobWheeler how does it overlap, please post the code in question with an example.

Comment: Im not sure what im on about bhansa sorry.

Comment: You didn't include any text in your original post, so I'm not sure what you mean about it "overlaps".

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```css
html,body { height: 100%; }
.back {
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/fresh_snow.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class='back'>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any results in the output, please check.

Comment: The body needs some height: `html,body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Thanks @showdev. Wasn't sure how it works.

Comment: @bhansa. Even though he got the answer. Have a look at this

Comment: Works perfect, put some text as well. looks nice

Answer (score 1):

You can use background image to your body or div.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.full{
    text-shadow:1px 1px #000;
    font-size: 6em;
    font-weight:700;
    margin:130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
 The Big Picture
</div>
```

Comment: I tried  html,body { height: 100%; }
.back {
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/fresh_snow.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%
} but nothing appears

Comment: you forgot to add, `http://` or `https://` in your image url.

Comment: Indeed i did forget well spotted seems to work now thanks

Comment: Happy to help!, feel free to ask.